# How can I set the grep after context to be "until the next blank line"?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

With grep I know how to set the context to a fixed number of lines. Is it possible to show a context based on an arbitrary string condition, like set after-context to "until the next blank line"?

Or possibly some other combination of tools?

Basically I have a log file of contiguous lines, with blank lines separating the "events" I want to search for a string in the log file, but show the whole event....

Comment: This is possible with other tools. If you post an example, you'll get specific answers.

Comment: You probably want to use `sed` or `awk` for that...

Comment: How can i do inverse of this. I have a log file with call stack. i dont want to print a call stack but want all other call stacks

Comment: I've been looking for this also, but for piping things into grep.

Comment: @pixelearth curious - did you find any of these to suit your need well?  I notice none have been accepted.

Comment: @Randall I haven't accepted anything because none of them fulfill the question about how to set the grep context. Since they use multiple other tools, the other answers can all be useful to others based on the number of upvotes. But none of them are more "right" to me than the others.

Answer (score 59):

It sounds like you need `sed`:

```
sed -n '/pattern/,/^$/p' file
```

Don't print by default (`-n`).  For lines that match `/pattern/` up to an empty line `/^$/`, print.

Comment: Note that this does not show the entire event, but misses those lines of the event preceding pattern.

Comment: To clearify: The command is of the format `'<address1>,<address2><function>'`. It finds inclusive address ranges (line ranges) starting with a match of `pattern` and ending with a match of a following empty line (matching `^$`). For each range function is executed (`p`: print incoming lines). In order to exclude empty lines from output use `sed -n '/pattern/,/^$/{/^$/!p}' file`. Here `/^$/!p` means print any incoming line not matching `^$`.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, with one exception: my source input had DOS-style newlines (\r\n), so I had to do this instead: `sed -n '/pattern/,/^\r$/p' file`

Comment: This works nicely if you don't have special characters in your match, if you're doing a match for directories, you're screwed.

Comment: @DmytroLysak — why?  `sed -ne '\%/home/user/bin/%p'` prints only the files under `/home/user/bin` in standard input.

Answer (score 32):

A simple solution is:

```
awk '/pattern/' RS= input-file
```

Setting RS to the empty string makes awk treat blank lines as the record separator, and the simple rule `/pattern/` causes awk to print any record that matches the pattern, which can be any extended regular expression.

Comment: This will show the entire event, including preceding lines (back to a blank line)

Comment: @Randall (better late than never, I suppose), the OP states "I want to search for a string in the log file, but show the whole event....", so showing the entire record is the desired behavior.

Comment: I agree; the whole event is desired, and this is a _really_ nice simple solution for that.  

The OP's title of the question is about how to "set the _'grep after'_ context, so my comment was really aimed at the TL;DR crowd who only read the title

Answer (score 9):

Here's a (tested) `awk` solution, separated onto multiple lines for readability:

```
awk '/pattern/ {do_print=1}
     do_print==1 {print}  
     NF==0 {do_print=0}' input_file
```

This script will also print the blank line so it's easier to visually separate the different matched blocks. If you don't want the blank line, swap the 2 lines `do_print==1 {print}` and `NF==0 {do_print=0}`

**Explanation:**

- `awk`: invoke the `awk` tool - it evaluates the input one line at a time sequentially.
- `'...'.`: everything enclosed by the single quotes is given to `awk` as instructions. In this case we perform the quoted instructions on each line.
- `/pattern/ {do_print=1}`: whenever a line contains "`pattern`", turn on the `do_print` flag
- `do_print==1 {print}`: if the `do_print` flag is set to on, print the current line.
- `NF==0 {do_print=0}`: NF stands for Number of Fields. `awk` delimits each line by spaces and tabs by default to break a line into fields. In this case trivially a blank line has no fields - so we turn off the `do_print` flag to stop printing when we see a line with `NF == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like the answer from @William Pursell as the before context is often useful (eg when grepping for things in `ini` files). If you actually want only the after context with `awk` you can do this:

```
$ cat demo.ini 
[foo]
aaa = 1
bbb = 2
ccc = 3

[bar]
eee = 8
fff = 0
ggg = 1

[baz]
xxx = 1
yyy = 0
zzz = 2
$ awk '/bar/,/^$/' demo.ini 
[bar]
eee = 8
fff = 0
ggg = 1

$ awk '/fff/,/^$/' demo.ini 
fff = 0
ggg = 1

$
```

Compare with the `RS=` version:

```
$ awk '/bar/' RS= demo.ini 
[bar]
eee = 8
fff = 0
ggg = 1
$ awk '/fff/' RS= demo.ini 
[bar]
eee = 8
fff = 0
ggg = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended the solution above to include empty line between the sections:

awk '/pattern/' RS= **ORS="\n\n"** input-file

Comment: This probably should be a comment to that other answer.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Right, I am new contributor so cannot add comment for other answer yet... 